# Why do some input elements have setSelectionRange property and how to test for whether it is actually supported?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, checkbox, html-input

I am pretty sure I used to test check boxes for the `setSelectionRange` property and they did not have one. But that seems to have changed in some browsers (tested Firefox and Chrome).

I used to do a check for the `setSelectionRange` property before making a selection like this:

```
if (el.setSelectionRange) {
  el.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
}
```

However, since check boxes appear to have the `setSelectionRange` property this throws an error.

So how do I test now for whether a selection can be made or not?

Here is also a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kb2ad5b5/

**Some background**

The test is in a parent's delegate event listener that selects the range in any element where this can be done.

Comment: Why do you check if a checkbox has a `setSelectionRange` property?

Comment: @Oriol I have a delegate event on a parent that selects all content of any element where this can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have a `setSelectionRange` because the method is defined in the [HTMLInputElement interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#htmlinputelement), and thus all inputs inherit it, even if they are checkboxes.

But of course [`setSelectionRange`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-textarea/input-setselectionrange) does not apply to all inputs, in that case it throws:

> For `input` elements, calling these methods while they [don't
>   apply](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#do-not-apply), and setting these attributes while they [don't apply](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#do-not-apply),
>   must throw an [`"InvalidStateError"`](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#invalidstateerror) [`DOMException`](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-DOMException); and
>   getting these attributes while they [don't apply](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#do-not-apply) must return null.
>   Otherwise, they must act as described below.

It only applies to [Text, Search](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#text-(type=text)-state-and-search-state-(type=search)), [URL](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#url-state-(type=url)), [Telephone](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#telephone-state-(type=tel)) and [Password](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#password-state-(type=password)) inputs.

So you can do something like

```
if (["text", "search", "url", "tel", "password"].indexOf(input.type) >= 0) {
  input.setSelectionRange(start, end);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a `try-catch` statement:

```
try {
  input.setSelectionRange(start, end);
} catch(err) {
  if (err instanceof DOMException && err.name === "InvalidStateError") {
    // setSelectionRange does not apply
  } else {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess one problem with the test is that it is not "future safe", i.e. if new element types are added that support a proper functioning `setSelectionRange` property then the function would still filter them out.

Comment: @Daniel Then use a `try-catch` statement.

Comment: Yes, maybe that is the only way. Strange that there exists no proper test for this function though.

Comment: With try/catch you'd not be able to distinguish not-supported from other errors though. Note on the "futuresafeness": with a new HTML spec providing new types there might be a new interface too. Attempting to call any `setSelectionRange()` method doesn't look like you've control over your code, I think.

Comment: @try-catch-finally You can check the error in `catch`, I added an example

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox has the `setSelectionRange()` method because it is defined for the interface of [`HTMLInputElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) elements.

```
interface HTMLInputElement : HTMLElement {
    ...
    void setSelectionRange(unsigned long start, unsigned long end, optional DOMString direction);
}
```

See the HTML5 W3C spec on forms: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html

To ensure the `input` element supports calls to `setSelectionRange()` you could maintain a whitelist of supported input types. So you may check for `/(text|password)/.test(el.type)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Any idea how to test for it properly?

Comment: Yes, the white list is a possibility but of course not perfect (think about new elements added to the specification then the white list would always have to be kept up to date).